# jquery: listings eq after not working if eq index is greater than number of elements in the list

Tags: jquery

Here is the working fiddle:- [code](https://jsfiddle.net/mujwtt7d/)

```
var _listings = $("#listings .listingContent");
_listings.eq(4).after("<li class=\"ad\">x</li>");
_listings.eq(9).after("<li class=\"ad\">x</li>");
```

When I try to insert li after 9th index i.e. 10th element, I am not able to do that as there are total 9 elements here.

Is there any way by which it gets inserted after the last possible element i.e. 9th element here instead of 10th element.

Similarly, if total li elements=8 and someone tries to insert after 10th element, it should be inserted after 8th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) is 0 based so if  you want to add an element after the last one, you should use the length minus 1, or [`last()`](https://api.jquery.com/last/) :

```js
var _listings = $("#listings .listingContent");

_listings.eq(3).after("<li class=\"ad\">x</li>");
_listings.last().after("<li class=\"ad\">x</li>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="listings">
  <li class="listingContent">1</li>
  <li class="listingContent">2</li>
  <li class="listingContent">3</li>
  <li class="listingContent">4</li>
  <li class="listingContent">5</li>
  <li class="listingContent">6</li>
  <li class="listingContent">7</li>
  <li class="listingContent">8</li>
  <li class="listingContent">9</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think you didn't get my questin

Comment: try doing _listings.eq(9).after("<li class=\"ad\">x</li>"); in your code and it won't work. I want to add 'x' at last even if you insert it after elemnent > list length. I want to add this element after last possible listing if the last you are looking for i.e. 10th here is missing

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a var to get what is the length of the collection.

```
var count=_listings.length;
_listings.eq(count).after("<li class=\"ad\">x</li>");
```